# Figuring out what object is closer to a certain point?

Tags: xna

I'm trying to create fog of war, I have the visual effect created but I'm not sure how to deal with the hiding of other players if they're within the fog of war.

So right now the thing I'm trying to do is if another player is hiding behind a wall then not to render that player. I was thinking of doing it by sending a ray in the direction of all the players, and then creating a list of all the obstacles that ray collides with and then trying to figure out if an obstacle was closer than the player in order to predict the distance.

But then I realized I'm not really sure how to figure out if the obstacle is infact closer or not because I have to account for all the dimensions, so I'm kind of stuck. First of all is this approach the correct way to go about it and secondly how would I calculate if the obstacle was infact closer taking into account the X Y and Z.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want to figure out players behind walls. I think what you want to figure out is how to determine what is foggy and what is not.

Comment: I also think you are giving us the description of your solution, rather than your original problem. rephrasing the question might help.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The more I thought about what I was trying to do the more ridiculous it sounded. I fixed it now using the solution in the first comment. Thanks to everyone for contributing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is only calculating the distance between two objects (while accounting for all dimensions) what you need is a simple formula for calculating vector's length.

First of all you need a position vector for each object/player, to get the distance between  two vectors you subtract position B from position A and then calculate the length using the following formula

> Vector3 Length = sqrt(X*X + Y*Y + Z*Z);

this formula is implemented in XNA using the Length function.

```
Vector3 vec = positionB - positionA; // subtract positions
float distance = vec.length();       // calculate distance
```

In fact you don't need to calculate the length, you can simply get away by calculating the length squared as far as you only test it with other length sqaured.

In case your objects have large widths/length calculating distance by using positions only might not be that accurate so you may want to substract the radius/width depending on the shape, even this might not be good enough, worst case might be sending a ray from the object's position to another object, getting the intersection point, and then using the new intersection point to calculate the distance.